# What are the life expectancies (ages) in the different realms of the gods?

Tags: god

In Buddhism, there are a few realms that exist. Does each realm have the same life expectancy, or does it vary from realm to realm?

Comment: There are 31 realms around one human world. Every realm has different life expectancy.

Comment: Look here https://www.dhammawiki.com/index.php/31_planes_of_existence .

Answer (score 0):

Different realms have different ages. But none of them lasts forever. There is realm spontaneous rebirth. Some states of existence extend to eons. No matter how long the realm exists it is not worthwhile to call it self.